# Changing the values of a class returned by the array [] operator

Tags: c#, .net

The question is: at the end of this code the value of ptArray[0].X is 3.33 or 1.11?

Thanks.

```
class MyPoint
{

  public double X, Y;

  public MyPoint(double x, double y)
  {
     X = x;
     Y = y;
  }
}

MyPoint[] ptArray = new MyPoint[2];

ptArray[0] = new MyPoint(1.11, 2.22);

MyPoint first = ptArray[0];

// Am I changing ptArray[0] here or not?
first.X = 3.33;
first.Y = 4.44;
```

Comment: You do have a C# compiler, right?

Comment: I think this is someone's homework.

Comment: It is not trivial as you might think, guys. Think about it. 'first' apparently points to the same address in memory of ptArray[0] but when you change first.X and Y you are not changing ptArray[0] instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not changing `ptArray[0]` itself, because that's a reference to the instance of `MyPoint`. However, you *are* changing the data within the object that it's referring to. So if you do:

```
first.X = 3.33;
Console.WriteLine(ptArray[0].X);
```

it will indeed print out 3.33.

Note that this *wouldn't* be true if `MyPoint` were a struct instead of a class. Although having mutable structs is a whole other realm of pain...

Answer (score 0):

```
3.33
```

because your `MyPoint` is classs unlike standard `Point` which is struct

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing your code and print the output of ptArray[0] to console.

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(ptArray[0].X + " " + ptArray[0].Y);
```

Then you will see it is changed to 3.33, 4.44